# Script which contains a Yes/No message box to close an application is not working

Tags: wpf, powershell, messagebox

I am attempting to write a script that will display a message box with yes/no buttons. I am wanting “Yes” to close an open application & “No” to end the script.

I have written a few mutations of the code below but the best I could get was both yes & no closed the application. Here’s my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Do you want to close TAS?',‘WARNING’,‘YesNo’)
[System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning

$msgBoxInput = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::Show(‘YesNo’)

   switch  ($msgBoxInput) {
       ‘Yes’ {
           Stop-Process -Name ATIS-Broadcaster2 
           ‘YES’
        }

        ‘No’ {
           Exit-PSSession
           ‘NO’
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```sh
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework

switch (
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(
    'Do you want to close TAS?',
    'WARNING',
    'YesNo',
    'Warning'
  )
) {
  'Yes' {
    'YES'
    #  Stop-Process -Name ATIS-Broadcaster2 
  }
  'No' {
    'NO'
    #  Exit-PSSession
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: I've also converted your "curly" single quotes to regular, ASCII-range ones; while PowerShell accepts both types, it's better to stick with the latter.</sup>

See the [`System.Windows.MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.MessageBox) docs.

Note that the parameters to which `'YesNo'` and `'Warning'` are passed, as well as the `.Show()` method's return value, expect / return *enumeration* values<sup>[1]</sup>.

However, PowerShell's automatic type conversions conveniently allow just specifying the value names as *strings*, such as `'YesNo'`, `'Warning'` or `'Yes'` in lieu of `[System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo`, `[System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning`, and `[System.Windows.MessageBoxResult]::Yes`, which simplifies the code.

---

<sup>[1] That is, instances of value types derived from [`System.Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum), which define discrete numeric values under symbolic names.</sup>